# What is this font?

Tags: html, css, fonts

I need to know which font is used in this photo and if it exists for Web, CSS, and HTML.

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bUL05.jpg)

Comment: This is more off topic on this site; however, sites like this may help. 

https://www.fontsquirrel.com/matcherator or

https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/

Comment: Is that photo a website you're looking at? if so inspect element, find it's font-family and you got your answer.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Comment: It is a photo not webpage =)

Comment: There's a Chrome extension called WhatFont that might help: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/whatfont/jabopobgcpjmedljpbcaablpmlmfcogm

Comment: The question is blatantly off topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pick some free fonts like Montserrat, Poppins or Quattrocento Sans from [Google Fonts library](https://fonts.google.com/?category=Sans%20Serif&thickness=4)

Comment: Nice suggestion, thanks =)

Answer (score 1):

It is **Hammer** icon its paid

Just go to this link and Type  **hammer**  in search  and you will see this icon under **Linearicons**

**https://icomoon.io/app/#/select**

Answer (score 0):

Font Squirrel have a tool for matching fonts, check it here:

https://www.fontsquirrel.com/matcherator?matcherator_img=j9lk4fzgjjhn30v6m5bu24kohek75dhf